# Does anyone know what these gold and dark green pieces make?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I have these LEGO pieces and I don't know what they go to.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Looks like *[Set #70503 - The Golden Dragon.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=70503-1)*

[image]

- I looked up this unique modified 2x2 brick to get a *[short list](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=48170&in=S)*
  of possible sets.

  [image]
- Visually, looked at the yellow/gold color scheme of the pieces in the
  bags to get a sense of the what to exclude when scrolling down said
  short list.
- Looked for crazy looking pieces from the bag to compare within the
  set.

  Like this piece here, *[part #64275 - Projectile Launcher, Bionicle Thornax 
  Launcher Half (Glatorian), Liftarm End 1 x 8](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64275&idColor=95#T=C&C=95)*.

  [image]
- and double confirmed the choice with *[part #54821 - Bionicle Zamor
  Sphere (Ball)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54821&idColor=108#T=C&C=20)*.

  [image]
- Just gotta be the Goldy D.

Comment: Nice work - mMy first idea would have been to look at the giant golden blades; but even if knowing its name, that thing still appears in 42 sets in gold.

Comment: Thx JB. Even at first glance the bag had at least four unique pieces I've never seen before. Green Ball, grey looking spine (?), long "yellow" blades, and a black modified 1x2 plate with side handles (?) (part# 92692).  So, I wasn't even sure if these were LEGO or some clone brand. Picture was too grainy to read logo on the studs, and the background wooden floor had me thinking the  "gold" was a yellow or tan in color.  I've dealt with that modified 2x2 brick in the past, so I knew that they were LEGO and started with a list on that piece.

Comment: Only 42 appearances? Sounds like a dream. Many "short" lists run for pages at 100 unique pieces per page.  Minifig searches.can be brutal.